# Media Query Height does not work in Mozilla

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries, mozilla

I've put a media query based on the height of the screen, however that code doesnt seem to work in firefox.

I tried this, still nothing:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  @media screen and ( min-height: 1024px){
    .sticky .order .item-list {
        max-height: 50vh !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE
I used the @media alone and it worked however when I refreshed the page, the problem recurs and the media query height doesn't work again.

```
@media screen and ( min-height: 1024px){
        .sticky .order .item-list {
            max-height: 50vh !important;
        }
      }
```

Comment: yes the CSS works outside of the height, it actually works for other browsers except for Mozilla. Where can i find the config? @MrLister

Comment: @MrLister Although I tried doing a simple css change using @-moz-document url-prefix() and it worked. I think the problem is with the media query using height

Comment: I've typed up an answer, because it became a bit too long for a comment. But now I'm not sure what you want to achieve anymore.Can you describe in words what needs to happen? What the query does now is whenever the window is higher than 1160px, the item-list will be no higher than half the window. I must say 1160px is quite large, though; I can only test that on my largest monitor, by pressing F11.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry if it was a bit confusing. I wanted to make the media query using height to work in Mozilla, since it doesnt work if i simply use @ media screen and ( min-height: 1160px ). So I then tried putting it inside @ -moz-document however that doesn't seem to solve the problem either. Did they discontinue the support for media query height in Mozilla?

Comment: No they didn't. See [this simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pxLqzmoa/3/) where the color of the text depends on the height of the viewport. Change the height of the output pane to see the difference. But like I said, 1160px is really large, are you sure that's what you meant?

Comment: Does my fiddle work for you? If so, can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to 1024px. The target screen is supposed to be PCs who have larger height sizes than normal. @MrLister

Comment: @MrLister Okay now that i used the code you placed in fiddle, It's now working in Mozilla as well although it is just the same code that I was using before. Thanks! But just a question, did you add anything more from the @ media i posted here?

Comment: I did make another fiddle earlier with your exact code (although I did change the min-height to 400 again to be able to test). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/hg8wzva2/6/). And that worked, so I concluded that the only thing wrong on your end could be the about:config entry. But it turned out this question is not about that, so I'm sorry, and I can't think of anything else to say now!

Comment: @MrLister Thanks for the help! Your fiddle worked but when i refreshed the page it stopped recognizing the media query height again. Might be a problem with the browser already not with the code.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using, and what OS?

Answer (score 0):

The `@-moz-document` at-rule in Firefox is hidden behind an about:config pref, which you have to enable first.

*Warning:* it is hidden for a reason. Apparently this is vulnerable to attacks. Or in the words of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@document):

> This has been limited to use only in user and UA sheets in Firefox 59 in Nightly and Beta — an experiment designed to mitigate potential CSS injection attacks (bug [1035091](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1035091)).

So proceed at your own risk!

---

To change an about:config setting

1. Type **about:config** in the location bar
2. If this is the first time you're doing this, a message will come up warning you about the dangers. Click the button "I'll be careful" or "I accept the risk" (the text on the button differs between Mozilla versions).
3. Search for the entry in the list (the list is sorted alphabetically), or, type the name of the entry in the Search box. In this case, you can just paste in **layout.css.moz-document.content.enabled** and then the result will only be this entry.
4. The value is set to **false**. Set it to **true** by double-clicking the line, and you're done. There is no "Save" or "Apply" button. You may have to press F5 on your webpage though.

If you've never worked with about:config before, you can read more about it here:
[Configuration Editor for Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox)